# RMarkdown to PPT: not loading reference_doc()

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to use a PPT template to format a RStudio > RMarkdown > PPT file.  Here's my testing file (saved as testing.Rmd):

````
---
title: "Aarduous Aardvarks"
author: "Aanonymous Aardvark"
date: "5/4/2019"
output: powerpoint_presentation
reference_doc: template.pptx
---

## My title

```{r myplot}
plot(mtcars)
```
````

When I first knit this, a PPT file was generated.  I opened that file, made the Slide Master background red and the font blue (deliberately hideous for testing), saved it as "template.pptx" in the same folder as above.

However, when I re-knit the document, the background is still white and the font is still black.  What do I need to get my template file recognized?

System:

- Windows 7 Professional
- Rstudio 1.2.1335
- Rmarkdown  1.12
- Pandoc: 2.6
- PPT 2010 v14.0.6129.5000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indentation in YAML is important. Use the structure as described in the [official docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html#ppt-templates):

```
---
title: "Aarduous Aardvarks"
output:
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had this same problem, but it does not repair when the YAML above is inserted. The additional changes helped me solve the problem:

1. Save the `reference_doc` as a `.potx` file format, and refer to that extension in the YAML header
2. Go into View -> Slide Master to make sure the slides in the master are the format you expect (one time I thought I made the changes, but they showed up on the Home menu and not the Slide Master)
3. Under the Home menu, click the Dropdown under Layout and make sure AT THE LEAST that you see these four elements:

   - Title
   - Section Header
   - Title and Content
   - Two Content

When all three of these are taken care of, my slides knit fine from the Rmd.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar error when knitting to a powerpoint template- the indentation as documented (indenting 'reference_doc:...') was giving me an error: "Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context", which suggested that the indentation was wrong in the YAML. I was able to resolve (through trial and error) with the following formatting:

```
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "Mike Harris"
date: "4/9/2021"
resource_files:
- template.pptx
output:
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---
```

Hopefully this saves someone a little extra time.

Comment: Not sure if your formatting is off or not, but indentation was the fix, and your answer lacks that.  Double check your post formatting - it might have gotten mis-formatted in posting.

Comment: @datakritter You are correct that my indentation was off- in the end, adding resource_files was the key for me. Thanks for catching that. I've updated my answer.